# How to remove a single record from many to many relationship in symfony usiing doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony, model-view-controller, doctrine

here are the the two classes  with the functions involved
section class has many to many relation with student class

```
class Section
{       
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyTOMany(targetEntity="Student",inversedBy="sections")
     */ 
    private $students;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->students = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add students
     *
     * @param \Blogger\sectionBundle\Entity\Student $students
     * @return Section
     */
    public function addStudent(\Blogger\sectionBundle\Entity\Student $students)
    {
        $this->students[] = $students;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove students
     *
     * @param \Blogger\sectionBundle\Entity\Student $students
     */
    public function removeStudent(\Blogger\sectionBundle\Entity\Student $students)
    {
        $this->students->removeElement($students);
    }

    /**
     * Get students
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getStudents()
    {
        return $this->students;
    }
}
```

and

```
   class Student {

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Section", mappedBy="students")
     */
    private $sections;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $studentId;



    public function __construct() {
        $this->sections = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add sections
     *
     * @param \Blogger\sectionBundle\Entity\Section $sections
     * @return Student
     */
    public function addSection(\Blogger\sectionBundle\Entity\Section $sections)
    {
        $this->sections[] = $sections;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove sections
     *
     * @param \Blogger\sectionBundle\Entity\Section $sections
     */
    public function removeSection(\Blogger\sectionBundle\Entity\Section $sections)
    {
        $this->sections->removeElement($sections);
    }

    /**
     * Get sections
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getSections()
    {
        return $this->sections;
    }
}
```

as in mysql

```sql
DELETE from student_section
where student_id = (select student.id from student where student.name="dummy")
And section_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for my misleading and unclear Question 
i found what i was searching for

```
//in the controller:
    $section = $em->getRepository('BloggersectionBundle:Section')->find(2);
    $student = $em->getRepository('BloggersectionBundle:Student')->findByStudentId("555555");
    $student->removeSections($section);
    $em->flush();
```

and in Student model

```
public function removeSections(Section $sections)
    {   
        $sections->removeStudent($this);
        $this->sections->removeElement($sections);
    }
```

and finally i edited the anotation in both student and section 
to cascade remove

```
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Section", mappedBy="students", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
```

Answer (score 0):

whats wrong with:

```
public function removeStudent(Student $student)
{
    $this->students->removeElement($student);
}
```

Comment: Hi, the answer is in "Low Quality Posts".  Would you please add a line of explanation to lift it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the generic doctrine command to generate getters and setters.

```
app/console doctrine:generate:entities NameSpace:Entity
```

Also you should read about synchronizing ManyToMany bidirectional relationships with Doctrine. [Here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#owning-and-inverse-side-on-a-manytomany-association) you can read about the *"adders"* but the same logic applies to remove methods.

EDIT - After question was updated

If I understood you correctly you want to remove a student from a section when you have the student name. The created `student_section` is a generated table from Doctrine. You can execute normal PDO statements in your Controllers or Repositories, but I would personaly implement a function in the model to keep it as OOP as possible.

```
public function removeStudentByName(Student $student)
{
    $toRemove = $this->students->filter(function (Student $s) use ($student) {
        return ($->getName() == $student->getname());
    });

    foreach ($toRemove as $student) {
        $this->students->remove($student);
    }

}
```

In a controller you can do something like:

```
//$student, $em is fetched
$section->removeStudentByName($student);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: getters and setters already added in my classes @Stiven LIupa

Comment: Than you have to implement the sync. logic as in the official documentation of Doctrine, and you should be set to use it in Controllers, Services etc @HatemTito